# Why do I get the error "Received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement" when using react-native?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library, jest-dom

I'm new to unit testing and I'm trying to render a component to learn more about the library.

I'm trying to follow [this](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-native-testing-library/example-intro) guide.

**Component**

```js
<TouchableOpacity
    style={style}
    onPress={onPress}
    accessibilityRole="button"
>
    <AppText style={textStyle}>{title.toUpperCase()}</AppText>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Test**

```js
it("Has the correct title in the button", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<AppButton title="Hello" />);
  
    expect(getByText("HELLO")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I'm simply trying to see that the component renders correctly but I get the error

```
received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {"_fiber": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 40, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": null, "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": -1, "alternate": null, "child": [FiberNode], "childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 1, "elementType": [Function Component], "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 0, "key": null, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 0, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [Component], "tag": 1, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": [Function Component], "updateQueue": [Object]}}
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, I'm using react-native-testing-library :)

Comment: I used testID and it's working as expected :)

Comment: Here is the working solution, it works if I access by testID. 

    it("Has the correct title in the button", () => {
      const { getByTestId } = render(<AppButton title="Hello" />);
      const eins = getByTestId("text");
      expect(eins.children[0]).toEqual("HELLO");
    });

Although it'd have been good to understand why I couldn't get the value with `getByText`, at least it's working. :)

Comment: In case anybody did the dumb thing that I did and stumbles upon this answer, I was using `findBy` which returns a promise - `await expect(findBy(...)).resolves.toBeInTheDocument()`

Answer (score 30):

You can use `waitFor`

Sample:

```
import { waitFor } from "@testing-library/react-native";


waitFor(() => expect(getByText("Your-text")).toBeInTheDocument());

// or

waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId("Your-Test-Id")).toBeInTheDocument());
```

Comment: waitFor works!!

Comment: I am using MDX for React. `waitFor` resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Note that `waitFor()` is async, so your tests should ```await waitFor(() => expect(getByText("Your-text")).toBeInTheDocument());```

Comment: waitFor works by await waitFor throws error

Comment: expect( screen.getByLabelText("testdata")).toBeInTheDocument(); worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

The issue is that you're trying to use the `toBeInTheDocument` helper function from `@testing-library/jest-dom` with React Native code. `@testing-library/jest-dom` expects DOM elements to be passed to its functions, and is meant to be used with `@testing-library/react` instead - it won't work with the native elements from React Native.

When using `@testing-library/react-native` you can assert the presence of an element like so.

```js
it("has the correct title in the button", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<AppButton title="Hello" />);
    expect(getByText("HELLO")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was doing the same mistake on not using testing lib methods

Answer (score 1):

whoever stumbles over this answer when searching for this error:

```
received value must be an htmlelement or an svgelement. 
received has type: object 
received has value: {}
```

I misused `findByText` and `getByText`.

so when I would wrap my `findByText` with a `waitFor` my tests succeeded, but they always succeeded no matter what I tested for. so just wrapping it with a `waitFor` might look like it solved the issue but actually you are not testing what you want.

the error indicates that the `findByText` returns a promise therefore the test fails because it wants an `HTMLElement`.